# Android Signal Processing

Tags: java, android, signal-processing

I am currently working on a project that involves the use of EEG signals on an android mobile phone.

I am deciding if I should make my own signal processing library for android or not because I can't seem to find any online.

Does anybody know of a library that I can use or would it be easier and faster to make my own?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to attach the java tag to this question. A lot of the people reading "processing" are looking at the open source framework www.processing.org , so adding "java" will get you more exposure.

Comment: @peppermcknight, this shouldn't have +signal+ and +processing+ as separate tags, instad use *singnal-processing* tag, those tags are misleading.

Answer (score 6):

I'm working on a similar project.  I am using the [NeuroSky MindSet EEG headset](http://store.neurosky.com/products/mindset) and Processing IDE with the [Ketai library](http://code.google.com/p/ketai/).  I could not get the NeuroSky Android API to work with either of my Android 2.3.4 or 4.0.1 phones.  When digging into why it didn't work, I got lost in their API's library and decided it would probably just be easier to read the data myself.  I modified the Ketai bluetooth program to read in the raw data, but did it in sort of a haphazard way (no checksum was performed).  It's quite a rough hack, but I got the data to draw on the screen and have not worked on it for a couple of weeks.  After I comment the code some more, I could put my code up on github - it'd be nice to get some collaboration.

By the way, if you did not intend for this to be for the Processing IDE of processing.org, you're quite lucky.  As Arcymag pointed out, the keyword "processing" might trigger a response from people like myself who receive emails for processing.org.  In any case, the Processing IDE has an Android mode that allows you to program Android under its IDE.  If you want to develop your program in say, the Eclipse IDE, you can export your project and take all of the power of Processing with you as a library.  After exporting, your code will be full Java.  There are only some minor differences between Java "proper" and how Processing presents Java anyhow (some aesthetic changes).  I prefer to work with the power of Processing because I am not actually a "proper" programmer, as my background is in physics, and Processing makes programming a joy.  (There are several questions regarding the differences between Java proper and Processing on stackoverflow.)

This is my first post on stackoverflow. I have been looking for a way to give back since this site has saved me countless hours on this project alone.  If you feel I deserve an upvote, you'd make one noob very happy.  I can do things such as: post more than two hyperlinks and upvote answers.

Comment: Hi,upvoted you!.. I am working on a similar project. I am unable to get the 512 raw values/second which neurosky claims the device sends .The values are highly fluctuating. Would you have a link to any source code of yours on github or something so that I could get some idea.

Comment: Here is my code: https://github.com/Plan99/KittyEEG.  Sorry it is so late coming.  By the way, I'm now working on a new project that you might be interested in: https://github.com/Plan99/BrainGoggles.  Cheers!